# what are the different resolution bounds for creating responsive mobile ui

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, mobile-application

what are the different resolution bounds i can keep for responsive design for which each resolution range have a separate design size so that in each resolution ranges it scales or resizes within it, what would be the different resolution bounds that covers all iPhone and Android devices

Right now i am using different designs for different sizes, like for iPhone 8, X and 13 pro max